# What does "NN" mean (submitting a proposal to a publisher)?

Tags: publishers

I recently heard about the possibility of submitting a proposal for a book to the publisher as "NN". I assume it has something to do with the fact that a couple of possible contributors have not yet confirmed their contribution but the editors want to go ahead anyway and submit the proposal already.

Am I right with my assumption? If so, what does "NN" stand for?

Comment: May be this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomen_nescio

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Nomen nominandum*, "a name to be named" - if you don't know the person's name yet, this indicates that you will supply the name later.

Which sounds a bit more reassuring than a simple *nomen nescio*, "I don't know the name".

Comment: I had only ever heard the second (in the plural - _nomen nescimus_) as the meaning of the abbreviation.

Answer (score 8):

I think "Nomen Nescio" is the correct expansion of NN.

My source:

```
Introduction to Scientific Publishing: Backgrounds, Concepts, Strategies By Andreas Öchsner; 
Page 77, table 7.3: "Some standard abbreviations from Latin language":
```

> N.N.  -- Uknown name, used as a placeholder for unknown names, (from Latin 'Nomen Nescio')

Google books [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=vA1accpGK5UC&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=nomen%20nescio%20publishing&source=bl&ots=gstQOx6CaC&sig=2_mrBDJVD3OsY9Xsz6jq_gM7SxU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qv2aVdifJ4XLogSdmaegAw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=nomen%20nescio%20publishing&f=false).